# check if date() is monday? java

Tags: java, date

Is there a way to check if a java `Date` object is Monday? I see you can with a `Calendar` object, but date? I'm also using US-eastern date and time if that changes indexing of monday

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(theDate);
boolean monday = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.MONDAY;
```

Comment: does getInstance() set the timezone?

Comment: The getInstance() method is overloaded in 4 versions: getInstance(), getInstance(Locale), getInstance(TimeZone) and getInstance(TimeZone, Locale).

Answer (score 11):

You can use `Calendar` object.

Set your date to calendar object using [setTime(date)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTime%28java.util.Date%29)

Example:

```
calObj.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.MONDAY
```

EDIT: As Jon Skeet suggested, you need to set TimeZone to Calendar object to make sure it works perfect for the timezone.

Answer (score 5):

The question doesn't make sense without two extra pieces of information: a time zone and a calendar system.

A `Date` object just represents an instant in time. It happens to be Wednesday in the Gregorian calendar in *my* time zone - but for some folks to the east of me, it's already Thursday. In other calendar systems, there may not even be such a concept of "Monday" etc.

The calendar system part is probably not a problem, but you *will* need to work out which time zone you're interested in.

You can then create a `Calendar` object and set both the time zone and the instant represented - or, better, you could use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) which is a *much* better date/time API. You'll still need to think about the same questions, but your code will be clearer.

Comment: how would I handle setting timezone based on location? I need to be able to set it for people in America and India

Comment: @JakeLong: It's hard to say without knowing more context. Is this a web app, or a client app, or what?

Comment: Ahh this is a web app, I'm using JSF to run Java

Comment: thus the reason I'm using date, I need to take a text input and convert it to a Date object first of all using `<f:convertDateTime>`

Answer (score 3):

You should use Calendar object for these checks. Date has weak timezones support. In one timezone this Date can be Monday, and in another timezone it is still Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

### Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:

Use `Instant` to represent a moment:

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
System.out.println(instant); // A sample output: 2021-07-03T09:07:37.984Z
```

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents an instantaneous point on the timeline in [UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc). The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for a zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

However, if you have got an object of `java.util.Date`, convert it to `Instant` e.g.

```
Date date = new Date(); // A sample date
Instant instant = date.toInstant();
```

Convert `Instant` to `ZonedDateTime` representing Date-Time in your timezone e.g.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
```

Check if the Date-Time falls on Monday e.g.

```
System.out.println(zdt.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY);
```

**Demo:**

```
import static java.time.DayOfWeek.SUNDAY;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.now();

        ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));

        System.out.println(zdt.getDayOfWeek() == SUNDAY);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
false
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/f5ANB4)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>