# Check from ArrayList in DB if equal

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-arrayadapter, android-cursor

I have a table that store two variables Days and percent’s. I want to assign them to a specific variable. From the Database Helper class, I’m getting the last 7 entries:

```
//----------------Graping the last seven elements ----------------------------------//
public ArrayList<StatsitcsHelper> GetWeaklyPrograss() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase ();

    Cursor cursor =  db.rawQuery ("select * from " + TABLE_PROGGRES, null);

    ArrayList<StatsitcsHelper> datas = new ArrayList<>();

    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst ();
        for (int i = cursor.getCount () - 7 ; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(i);
            StatsitcsHelper data = new StatsitcsHelper();
            data.WeakleyDate= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_P_Date));
            data.WeakleyPercent = cursor.getInt (cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_P_Percentage));
            datas.add(data);
            cursor.moveToNext ();
        }
        cursor.close ();
    }
    return datas;
}
```

I want to build if statement that will say if day is Saturday then assign Saturday Percent Variable is Statistics Class to the percent associated from the database. Same goes for Sunday ….etc.

Inside the Statistics Class:

```
public void WeaklyStatstics(){

    int saturday = 0,
        sunday = 0,
        monday = 0,
        tuesday = 0,
        wednsday = 0,
        thersday = 0,
        friday = 0;

StatsitcsHelper statsitcsHelper = new StatsitcsHelper ();
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper (getActivity ());

//---------------------TO DO----------------------------------------//
}}
```

I don’t know how to analysis  each item from the list in the database to another class.

Here is the Insertion of the Table:

```
    // ----------------Proggres Table ------------------------------------//
public boolean insertPrograss(String Date, Integer percentage) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase ();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues ();

    contentValues.put (COL_P_Date, Date);
    contentValues.put (COL_P_Percentage, percentage);


    long result = db.insert (TABLE_PROGGRES, null, contentValues);
    db.close ();
    return result != -1;
}
```

the method is called by scheduler that will store the date into just day by using date formate, and the output will be  Monday, 87.

i want to write  a method to get the last 7 inputs through GetWeaklyPrograss method. and assign it to the variables something like this

```
        if(statsitcsHelper.WeakleyDate.equals ("monday")){
        saturday = statsitcsHelper.WeakleyPercent;
    }
```

and here is the statsitcsHelper:

```
public class StatsitcsHelper {

//-------------- Weakly Progress -----------------------/
public String WeakleyDate;
public int WeakleyPercent;


}
```

Comment: question is not clear.Could you rephrase it .

Comment: I have a Weakly bar chart that available inside the Statistics class, I’m trying to grab variables from the database table that have day and percent fields. The if statement will see what day it is and assign the percent value to the right variable to assign to the chart

Comment: It means , you have the date and you want to change it to the week day?

Comment: no its Stored as days, So its Good to go

Comment: So what is your problem ? I didnt understand.

Comment: I don’t know how to take each row from the table and check the day and send it to the right bar chart.

Comment: Can you post some example table data .

Comment: In which data type do you want the data. I mean int array?

Comment: i prefer stringArray if possible

Comment: It means your WeaklyStatstics method will return a string array right?

Comment: i added the insertPrograss method to better understanding. im sorry for all the confusions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this logic ,

```
public void WeaklyStatstics(){

        int saturday = 0,
                sunday = 0,
                monday = 0,
                tuesday = 0,
                wednsday = 0,
                thersday = 0,
                friday = 0;

        //StatsitcsHelper statsitcsHelper = new StatsitcsHelper ();
        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper (getActivity());

        ArrayList<StatsitcsHelper> statsitcsHelperList = databaseHelper.GetWeaklyPrograss();

        for (StatsitcsHelper statsitcsHelper : statsitcsHelperList)
        {
            if(statsitcsHelper.WeakleyDate.equals("Monday")){
                monday = statsitcsHelper.WeakleyPercent;
            }else if (statsitcsHelper.WeakleyDate.equals("Tuesday")){
                tuesday = statsitcsHelper.WeakleyPercent;
            }
            //todo and write for other days too     
        }

        // In here you can use all valid  data


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what the problem is.

However to check the day of week, you can get some ideas from this:

[check if date() is monday? java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080391/check-if-date-is-monday-java)

On a side note:
Your cursor contains all of the data in the table! It is usually better to get the results you want (last seven elements) on your cursor.

Limit your DB query, down to the interesting data. Instead of taking all data from the DB (select * from), you should specialize your query.
Look for SQL expressions ORDER BY, ASC, DESC, LIMIT, and you will get there.

Comment: the date field is storing a string of what day it is. how can i read each row of the table and check the string if equal and assign to the write place, sudko code: bring one row by GetWeaklyPrograss and see date field if equal Saturday then Saturday variable = that row percent

Comment: you could just replicate the code that you already have for the seven days:   if(statsitcsHelper.WeakleyDate.equals ("monday")){
        saturday = statsitcsHelper.WeakleyPercent;
    }

Comment: GetWeaklyPrograss is inside the DatabaseHelper where it iterate inside the list to bring the 7 rows. the work should be inside the Statistics class where it should read each row and check if its monday then it assign the percentage to an int variable there